# MySQL 8 Couldn't execute FLUSH TABLES Access denied

Tags: permissions, mysql-8.0

I have MySQL 8 database with a user to whom I grant ALL privileges as follows:

```
GRANT ALL ON test_db.* TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

When I login to mysql as this user and run the following command I get error saying `ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD or FLUSH_TABLES privilege(s) for this operation`

```
FLUSH TABLES;
```

I thought the GRANT ALL permission would have already given this user the RELOAD or FLUSH_TABLES privilege(s)?

How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Global Privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges)

> Global privileges are administrative or apply to all databases on a
> given server. To assign global privileges, use ON *.* syntax.
>
> The CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE USER, FILE, PROCESS, RELOAD, REPLICATION
> CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SHOW DATABASES, SHUTDOWN, and SUPER static
> privileges are administrative and can only be granted globally.

[RELOAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload)

The RELOAD enables the following operations:

- Use of the FLUSH statement.
- etc

Conclusion , you need the reload privilege which can be given :

```
GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

Comment: so what you are saying is I'd have to give it as a global privilege as opposed to being able to restrict to a specific database?

Comment: @adam78 yes, global privileges apply to all databases, you can't restrict to only one specific db.